# How to create a row by dividing First row by third row

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataset which has values in first row & total in third row. I want to create a fourth row which is percentage of first by total which can be done by dividing first row with fourth row.

below is structure of dataframe

```
ds = structure(list(t1 = structure(c("1", "2", "Total"), label = "currently smoke any tobacco product", labels = c(no = 0, 
yes = 1), class = "haven_labelled"), c1Female = c(679357.516868591, 
8394232.81394577, 9073590.33081436), c1Male = c(2254232.8617363, 
5802560.20343018, 8056793.06516647), se.c1Female = c(63743.4459540534, 
421866.610586848, 485610.056540901), se.c1Male = c(185544.754820322, 
386138.725133411, 571683.479953732), Total_1 = c(`1` = 2933590.37860489, 
`2` = 14196793.0173759, `3` = 17130383.3959808), per = c(`1` = 0.171250713471665, 
`2` = 0.828749286528335, `3` = 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

My try & what is wrong with this

```
ds %>% mutate(percentage = .[1,]/.[3,])
```

OUTPUT SHOULD BE : Below is the dput of Output Dataframe that I want

```
structure(list(t1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "Percentage", "Total"), class = "factor"), c1Female = c(679357.517, 
8394232.814, 9073590.331, 0.074871963), c1Male = c(2254232.86, 
5802560.2, 8056793.07, 0.279792821), se.c1Female = c(63743.446, 
421866.611, 485610.057, 0.131264674), se.c1Male = c(185544.755, 
386138.725, 571683.48, 0.324558539), Total_1 = c(2933590.38, 
14196793.02, 17130383.4, 0.171250714), per = c(0.171250713, 0.828749287, 
1, 0.171250713)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L
))
```

Do share the tidyverse way to do this. Also, do tell what is wrong with this approach below line code

```
ds %>% mutate(percentage = .[1,]/.[3,])
```

Comment: akrun's solution below should work, but why are you storing sample data row-wise? Tidy-data practice recommends the reverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `summarise_at` to divide multiple column values to return a single row and then bind with the original dataset

```
library(dplyr)
ds %>% 
    summarise_at(-1, ~ .[1]/.[3]) %>%
    mutate(t1 = 'Percentage') %>%
    bind_rows(ds, .)
#       t1     c1Female       c1Male  se.c1Female    se.c1Male      Total_1       per
#1          1 6.793575e+05 2.254233e+06 6.374345e+04 1.855448e+05 2.933590e+06 0.1712507
#2          2 8.394233e+06 5.802560e+06 4.218666e+05 3.861387e+05 1.419679e+07 0.8287493
#3      Total 9.073590e+06 8.056793e+06 4.856101e+05 5.716835e+05 1.713038e+07 1.0000000
#4 Percentage 7.487196e-02 2.797928e-01 1.312647e-01 3.245585e-01 1.712507e-01 0.1712507
```

---

Or another option is `add_row`

```
ds %>%
   add_row(t1 = 'Percentage') %>% 
   mutate_at(-1, ~ replace_na(., .[1]/.[3]))
```

---

Or do this within the `add_row` step itself

```
ds %>% 
   add_row(t1 = 'Percentage', !!!as.list(.[-1][1,]/.[-1][3,]))
 #      t1     c1Female       c1Male  se.c1Female    se.c1Male      Total_1       per
#1          1 6.793575e+05 2.254233e+06 6.374345e+04 1.855448e+05 2.933590e+06 0.1712507
#2          2 8.394233e+06 5.802560e+06 4.218666e+05 3.861387e+05 1.419679e+07 0.8287493
#3      Total 9.073590e+06 8.056793e+06 4.856101e+05 5.716835e+05 1.713038e+07 1.0000000
#4 Percentage 7.487196e-02 2.797928e-01 1.312647e-01 3.245585e-01 1.712507e-01 0.1712507
```

Comment: do you need the `~` if you are calling the function as the second argument?

Comment: @Dij  It is an anonymous funciton call, removing that results in error

Comment: Thanks! Will it replace `function(x) x[1]/x[3]` outside of `tidyverse` calls? if you know...

Comment: @Dij Yes, it is a short form of that

Comment: Thanks @akrun, I just have a doubt though, what if I doubt want ds in last bind_rows line, I am already using a complex computation to come till there & ds is actually not so simple as I gave in example, its a multi level chaining and hence cant attribute ds in bind_rows(), please suggest

Comment: @VaibhavSingh  Can you try the `add_row` version I updated